# setInterval in function keeps speeding and clear interval is ignored

Tags: javascript

When I activate `showMoves()` the `setInterval` is supposed to repeat the function one second at a time.

However, it speeds up after a few seconds and activates the function several times in a single second instead of once. Also the `clearInterval` isn't working even though the `if` statement for it turns `true`.

```js
let i = -1;

function showMoves() {
  const start = setInterval(showMoves, 1000);

  if (i > game.computerMoves.length) {
    clearInterval(start);
  }

  console.log(i + ' ' + game.computerMoves.length);

  const showColors = new Map([
    [green, 'lime'],
    [yellow, 'rgb(255,255,102)'],
    [blue, 'dodgerblue'],
    [red, 'salmon'],
  ]);

  i++;

  let move = game.computerMoves[i];

  move.style.backgroundColor = showColors.get(move);

}
```

Comment: You are creating a new interval every time setInterval calls showMoves. They are not speeding up, you just have more than one starting at different times.

Comment: Consider changing `setInterval` to `setTimeout` - `setInterval` is recurring and it seems your logic in designed for a one-shot event that reschedules itself.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be calling `setInterval` inside the very same function that's being called by `setInterval` -- you're setting up multiple interval timers that way, not just one that you can clear away easily. It's "speeding up" as you say because you're seeing more and more different interval timers calling the same function.

Answer (score 0):

You're recursively calling `showMoves` - every second, a new interval is created. When the function runs and the stop condition *isn't* reached, the `start` reference you have to the interval you just created is just garbage collected. You want a method to save the intervals so that you can reference them later so they can be cleared. For example:

```
let intervals = [];
function showMoves() {
  intervals.push(setInterval(showMoves, 1000));

  if (i > game.computerMoves.length) {
    // clear all currently running intervals:
    intervals.forEach(clearInterval);
    intervals = [];
  }
  // ...
```